# jQuery Tab with ASP.NET forms postbak

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using the jQuery tabs with ASP.NET forms and I noticed the selected tab does not persist after postback. 
I used the solution below with the latest jQuery however it only works on Firefox. With IE and Chrome it does not work.

Here is the block of code in the asp.net page:

```
<div>

           <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTab" runat="server"  Value="0"  />

        <div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. </p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. </p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. </p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Below is the javascript code I am using:

```
//Activate the tabs
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

        /* Keep the selected tab across postbacks */
       $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function () {
                var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
                $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
            },
            active: document.getElementById('<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID%>').value
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any Idea why it works on Firefox but not on Chrome or IE?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't registering the actual script to make the state change:

I had this issue some time ago and ended up using a hidden element to solve it.

You need to add the following registered script block to the initial PostBack to trigger the change when not posting back:

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "selecttab", "$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: " + hidLastTab.Value + " });", true);
}
```

On the ASPX page add a hidden field that stores the tab index:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidLastTab" runat="server" value="0" />
```

Add to the script after $(selector).tabs() is invoked to update the hidden field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").on('tabselect'), function (event, ui) {
        var selectedTab = ui.index;
        $("#<%=hidLastTab.ClientID%>").val(selectedTab);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the solution and the selection persists across postbacks however I lose the formatting of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, i.e. re-applies the tabs and sets the correct tab after each postback:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=appTabs.ClientID %>").tabs({
        activate: function() {
            var selectedTab = $('#<%=appTabs.ClientID %>').tabs('option', 'active');
            $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
        },
        active: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
        }).css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```